# Find Records form date field and time field in one day before in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following structure as a table, I want to select the record from one day before, I have tried the following query for selecting the record.

```
SELECT slot_date, slot_time FROM slot_booking WHERE slot_date =
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

[image]

assume if today is (2018-04-03) time is 09 (24hr Format) I want to select a record from DB 2018-04-04 TIME between 09:00:00 to 9.30:00

i am struggling  with compare time field, if you have any suggestion or solution post you answer

Comment: This is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570882/mysql-how-to-select-date-field-exactly-7-days-before-today-and-for-time-last-1-h

Comment: If today is 2018-04-03. surely you want records from 2014-04-02, not 2014-04-04?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Concat date and time fields, use str_to_date to convert to datetime then use date_add or date_sub as required

```
 SET @DT = '2018-04-14';
SET @T  = '09:00:00';
set @now = '2018-04-13 09:00:00';
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@DT,@T),'%Y-%m-%d%H:%i:%s') dt,
         case when STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@DT,@T),'%Y-%m-%d%H:%i:%s') 
            between date_add(@now, interval 24 hour) and date_add(date_add(@now, interval 24 hour),interval 30 minute) then 'true'
         else 'false'
         end as inrange;

+---------------------+---------+
| dt                  | inrange |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2018-04-14 09:00:00 | true    |
+---------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: A better idea would be to store date and time as a single entity to begin with